# How to call separate code for every single prop in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I would like to make useEffect method, which is calling when any prop is changed but not all the code, just a single one dedicated for this props

I imagine something like that ...
In this moment all the code is called whed one, two or three is changed.

```
const SomethingComponent = (props: any) => {
   const {one, two, three} = props;

   useEffect(() => {
      if(something for one props){
         code for one
      }

      if(something for two props){
         code for two
      }

      if(something for three props){
         code for three
      }
   }, [one, two, three]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different hooks, and give each of them a single dependency. This way only that specific `useEffect` will fire when the dependency changes:

```
const SomethingComponent = (props: any) => {
    const { one, two, three } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        // code for one
    }, [one])

    useEffect(() => {
        // code for two
    }, [two])

    useEffect(() => {
        // code for three
    }, [three])

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you ;) I thought that I can use ```useEffect``` only once